# Django models update related object when relation is updated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, django, django-models, django-templates

Ruby on Rails has a notion called `touch`.

This is helpful in situations where you have objects linked via foreign keys and you want to conditionally update, say the parent's `updated_at` field, whenever the child is updated. This can then be used efficiently for Russian Doll caching amongst other useful things.

[Per the Rails docs:](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#russian-doll-caching)

---

```rb
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :games
end

class Game < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :product, touch: true
end
```

With `touch` set to `true`, any action which changes `updated_at` for a game record will also change it for the associated product, thereby expiring the cache.

---

I tried to find an equivalent way in Django for achieving this but I haven't found an elegant solution. How can I force update `Product.updated_at` whenever `Game.updated_at` is altered?

```py
class Product(models.Model):
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField()

class Game(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField()
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way to implement this is to override the `.save()` method:

```py
class Product(models.Model):
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class Game(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.product:
            self.product.save()
```

Note that the addition of [`auto_now=True`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now) will cause the timestamps to be automatically updated when the instance is saved.